# What is the unit of autocorrelation function?

Tags: autocorrelation, fourier

In general, for autocorrelation of the deterministic signals,from the formula what is the unit of it.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  Normalized autocorrelations have no units because the units are divided out as part of the normalization process.

Non-normalized autocorrelations have the original data's units squared.