# Physical interpretation of 4th-order correlations

Tags: correlation, random-process

BACKGROUND:

Let's say we have samples of a random process $X(t)$ at two different times, $t_1$ and $t_2$, denoted $X(t_1), X(t_2)$.  The values of $X(t)$ represent some voltage-like quantity (i.e. a voltage, current, or field). Assume $X(t)$ is a zero-mean, real-valued wide-sense stationary (WSS) process.

For the second-order statistics,  we usually treat the quantity $\mathbb E[X^2(t)]$ as the average power.
The expectation $\mathbb E[X(t_1) X(t_2)]$ is just the autocorrelation function evaluated at lag $\tau = t_2-t_1$.

QUESTION:

Is there some physical interpretation of the *4th-order* correlations, i.e. $\mathbb E[X^3 (t_1)X(t_2)]$, $\mathbb E[X^2 (t_1)X^2(t_2)]$, and $\mathbb E[X (t_1) X^3(t_2)]$?

Comment: I'll counter-ask: What's the *physical interpretation* of the autocorrelation?

Comment: I wonder if this could be considered, conceptually, a duplicate of [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25067/what-is-the-unit-of-autocorrelation-function). This was the first thing that came to my mind when trying to infer the physical meaning from the units. In any case, autocorrelation is a product, between two time series of the same unit, so it is that unit squared. So, voltage squared gives you power. But $X^2(t)$ would already be "Power" and the autocorrelation of that would be Power squared...So, not very helpful..What motivated the question?

Comment: @CarlosDanger that's a pretty different question that you're asking!! And the answer is: you can't. I can give you a signal that has pretty much zero autocorrelation, but high $\mathbb E\left[ X^2(t)  X^2(t+\tau) \right]$. But then I can give you a signal with the same $\mathbb E\left[ X^2(t)  X^2(t+\tau) \right]$, but very different autocorrelation.

Comment: @CarlosDanger PDF $\equiv$ moment generating function ($\equiv$ characteristic function) hence  IMHO, in general you cannot compute higher order moments from lower order ones.

Comment: I think you guys are getting too caught up in my example "motivation", so I've deleted it. For now, I'm just looking for the answer to the literal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to relax the WSS assumption, and consider cyclostationary signals, you might check out my theory of pure and impure sine-wave components of higher-order probabilistic parameters:

[On pure and impure sine-waves, higher-order moments, and cyclic cumulants](http://cyclostationary.blog/2016/02/14/cyclic-temporal-cumulants)

and

[Oddities concerning pure nth-order sine waves](http://cyclostationary.blog/2017/04/05/more-on-pure-and-impure-sine-waves)

I've thought about your question a lot, more so in the past than lately, and all I've been able to come up with is that higher-order moments contain characteristic sine-wave components (characteristic of the process, the order, and the number of conjugated factors), and higher-order cumulants characterize what is new in the moment that cannot be accounted for by products of lower-order moments. Unlike the easy physical interpretation of autocorrelation as power (think of the zero-lag autocorrelation), I don't have a simple physical unit to assign here, but maybe my hint will lead you to a more satisfying answer.